# How to check folders size in Windows without showing all subfolder files?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, cmd.exe, user-folders

Is there a CMD command to show the folder size in side a directory?

I know I can dir /s/a and see all the sizes of files inside folders and subfolders of directory.
However I am trying to find a log file in the Windows directory folder so was trying to find properties (like if you right clicked and got properties using the GUI).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides [`du` (Disk Usage utility)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/du.aspx) as a part of the SysInternals suite.

You can run:

```
du.exe <folder>
```

To get statistics like:

```
Files:        18
Directories:  3
Size:         11,459,083 bytes
Size on disk: 11,505,696 bytes
```

To show statistics only for the folder without subfolders add the `-n` argument:

```
du.exe -n <folder>
```

Comment: Is there a du command to show a range of folders?

Comment: What do you mean by a "range"?

Comment: I looked at some of the use cases at it looks like it will be a good tool for finding the problem I am looking for.